# background-image not displaying image - but <img tag is displaying image with same URL path

Tags: html, css

I am using background-image:url('image') to include some icons within my HTML page. However, a white space is displayed and the image is not there. I am using an empty  tag. When I use  tag the image displays successfully. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```css
#adventureIcon {
  background-image: url("../icons/Kayak01.png");
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<li class="menuItem">
  <a class="icon_navigation" href="#adventure" id="adventure">
    <i class="iconNav" id="adventureIcon"> </i>
    <span class="icon_name">
          Adventure
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding backgroud-size property. May be your image is too big that it will be unable to recognise.

Comment: would you sent us the link to the site you are doing this. or a screenshot of the dev tools ?

Comment: By inspecting, I found that you are accessing image which is not exist. I think you are access https://stacksnippets.net/icons/Kayak01.png which is not exist or path is wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that in the CSS, the URL will be relational to the external CSS document. While the `<img>` tag's URL will be relational to the HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your path is correct, you can add display block to your class it will display with the correct height and width:

```css
#adventureIcon {
  background: url("https://www.rei.com/content/dam/images/Expert%20Advice/Migration/HeroImages/Van_Dragt_092217_1030_kayaking_basics_lg.jpg");
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

#adventureIcon2 {
  background: url("https://www.rei.com/content/dam/images/Expert%20Advice/Migration/HeroImages/Van_Dragt_092217_1030_kayaking_basics_lg.jpg");
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<li class="menuItem">
  <a class="icon_navigation" href="#adventure" id="adventure">
    <i class="iconNav" id="adventureIcon"></i>
    <div class="iconNav"></div>
    <span class="icon_name">        
                        Adventure
                        </span>
  </a>
</li>

<li class="menuItem">
  <a class="icon_navigation" href="#adventure" id="adventure2">
    <i class="iconNav" id="adventureIcon2"></i>
    <div class="iconNav"></div>
    <span class="icon_name">        
                        Adventure
                        </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Down vote why it doesn't work without it and it does with?? His path is local so I can't use it but the snippet clearly shows if the path is correct this will work.

Comment: I hadn't paid attention to that part, but `<i>` is an inline element, so it would indeed ignore width/height definitions.

Comment: Yea I am not sure why he wants to put an image into what is usually just used to italicize text but this makes it show up lol.

Comment: I've seen this happening more these days. `<i>` becoming colloquially used - apparently for "Icon" or similar.